# Jenkins with Copy Artifact plugin: copy directory contents with subdirectories

Tags: jenkins, ant, configuration, copy, continuous-integration

I have a structure of artifacts in another build:

```
/
/bundle/docs
/bundle/bin
/bundle/bin/scripts
```

I want to copy all files and sudirectories into the current job's workspace subfolder 'product1' from /bundle/bin. I expect to see in %WORKSAPCE%/product1 contents of /bundle/bin.

I've configured it like this:

Artifacts to copy: bundle/bin/**

But it creates *%WORKSAPCE%/product1//bundle/bin* instead.

**Is it possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that's just how the plugin works. Your options are:

1. Keep the same configuration and manipulate directories later using sh `mv` (Linux) or cmd `move` (Windows) command. This is the workaround used in my environment.
2. Check the "Flatten directories" option (but this will mix together the `/bundle/bin` and `/bundle/bin/scripts`)
3. Improve the plugin and contribute your code to the community :-)

Comment: Adding "Base Directory"  parameter would solve the problem. It should cut off "base directory" part from the file path during the paste of copied files into workspace.

Comment: I've ended up whith option 1.

Comment: As I see authors has already know that issue and planned it in Copy Artifact 2.0 (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Preview+for+Copy+Artifact+2.0)  , see "Source base directory" param.

Comment: Update for anyone wondering in 2023... the Copy Artifact 2.0 idea was abandoned and the Copy Artifact plugin got into maintenance mode since September 2017. Looks like in 2023 some maintainers started pushing some minor new features but still, almost everything is bug fixes. No feature for solving this yet...